# Quadratic optimization problem with quadratic constraint

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming

Given  $A = A^T \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, X = \begin{bmatrix}x & \eta\end{bmatrix} \text{with} \ x, \eta \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $||x|| = ||\eta|| = 1$ (vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are treated as columns) solve

$$ \min_{v \in \mathbb{R}^2} f(v):= v^TX^TAXv$$ such that $$ h(v):=v^TX^TXv-1 = 0 $$

**First attempt**:
Construct the Lagrangian, 
$L := f(v) + \lambda h(v)$

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial v} = 2(X^TAX)v + 2\lambda(X^TX)v = 0$$
Premultiply by $v^T$ to get

$$\lambda = -v^TX^TAXv $$

Substituting this back yields a very complicated equation in $v$ which I'm unable to solve.

**Second attempt**:
Since $X^TAX$ is symmetric, $v^TX^TAXv \ge ||v_m||^2 \lambda_{\min}(X^TAX)$ where $v_m$ is the eigenvector corresponding to the least eigenvalue $\lambda_{\min}(X^TAX)$ of $X^TAX$. Therefore the minimizer of the original problem is $v = \alpha v_m$ with $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(v) = 0$.

My second attempt is still a hunch, and I'm not being able to prove the correctness of my hunch.

**Question** : I'm looking for a complete solution or hints to any of my approaches in order to get an analytical solution to the minimization problem.

The solution to this has been given in the book, but without proof, and I am unsuccessful at getting the same solution. The given minimizer for $v$ is the eigenvector of the smaller eigenvalue of $X^TAX$ scaled appropriately such that the norm is 1.

Answer (score 2):

This is the definition of generalized eigenvalues, i.e. you are looking for the minimum generalized eigenvalue of the pair $(X^TAX, X^TX)$.

Comment: Can you please post some reference from where I can study this?

Comment: Just random google hit http://www.svcl.ucsd.edu/courses/ece271B-F09/handouts/Dimensionality3.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the problem correctly.

Let:

- 2 by 2 matrix $B = X^{T}AX$,
- 2 by 2 matrix $C = X^{T}X$

Then:

- Objective: $f(x) = \vec{v} B \vec{v} $
- Constraint: $g(x) = \vec{v} C \vec{v} - 1 = 0$

$f(x) = (b_{11}v_{1} + b_{21}v_{2})v_{1} + (b_{12}v_{1} + b_{22}v_{2})v_{2}$

$f(x) = b_{11}v_{1}^{2} + b_{21}v_{2}v_{1} + b_{12}v_{1}v_{2} + b_{22}v_{2}^{2}$

$g(x) = c_{11}v_{1}^{2} + c_{21}v_{2}v_{1} + c_{12}v_{1}v_{2} + c_{22}v_{2}^{2} - 1$

Lagrange:

$L = f(x) + \lambda g(x)$

$0 = \frac{\partial L}{\partial v_{1}} = 2b_{11}v_{1} + b_{21}v_{2} + b_{12}v_{2} + \lambda (2c_{11}v_{1} + c_{21}v_{2} + c_{12}v_{2})$

$0 = \frac{\partial L}{\partial v_{2}} = 2b_{22}v_{2} + b_{12}v_{1} + b_{21}v_{1} + \lambda (2c_{22}v_{2} + c_{12}v_{1} + c_{21}v_{1})$

$0 = c_{11}v_{1}^{2} + c_{21}v_{2}v_{1} + c_{12}v_{1}v_{2} + c_{22}v_{2}^{2} - 1 $

Comment: Your interpretation is indeed correct. I found it easier to keep it in the form of matrices instead of their individual elements though.

Comment: Diagonalize the constraint. Optimize with a change of basis. http://www.math.ucla.edu/~archristian/teaching/33a-f16/optimization-of-quadratic-forms.pdf

Comment: Why do you want a close form for the solution? Do you have to calculate this very quickly? 2 by 2 is tiny.

Comment: Analytical solution since I want to compare it to the solution mentioned in the book (the book doesn't give a proof).

Comment: What is the solution in the book? I think I want to know.

Comment: Edited the question with the required data.

Comment: @R zu were you able to get any new insight on this?